# Knockout JS - concatenate function name with array value

Tags: javascript, knockout.js

I have the following piece of code:

VIEW:

```
<div class="form-group days-of-week">
<!-- ko foreach: $root.daysOfWeek --> // array of week days
  <label class="col-sm-2 control-label" data-bind="text: dayOfWeek"></label> // 'dayOfWeek' being week day name, e.g. Monday, Tuesday etc.
  <div class="col-sm-10 description">
    <input type="hidden" value="0" data-bind="attr: { name: 'ScheduledRequest[DayOfWeek][' + dayOfWeek + ']' }" />
    <input type="checkbox" data-bind="checked: $parent.schedule().Friday, value: 1, attr: { name: 'ScheduledRequest[DayOfWeek][' + dayOfWeek + ']' }" class="form-control" />
  </div>
<!-- /ko -->
```

The `data-bind` in this part `data-bind="checked: $parent.schedule().Friday` should call the function whose name is the current `dayOfWeek` (in this hardcoded example, `Friday` - which works as expected for this particular day) in the `schedule` model. However, `data-bind="checked: $parent.schedule().dayOfWeek` with call function `dayOfWeek` in the `schedule` model which isn't what I want. I tried doing the following:

VIEW

`checked: $parent.getCurrentDay(dayOfWeek)`

MODEL:

```
self.getCurrentDay = function(day) {
var dayOfWeek = "";
if(day == 'Monday')
  dayOfWeek = '$parent.schedule().Monday';
if(day == 'Tuesday')
  dayOfWeek = '$parent.schedule().Tuesday';
if(day == 'Wednesday')
  dayOfWeek = '$parent.schedule().Wednesday';
if(day == 'Thursday')
  dayOfWeek = '$parent.schedule().Thursday';
if(day == 'Friday')
  dayOfWeek = '$parent.schedule().Friday';
if(day == 'Saturday')
  dayOfWeek = '$parent.schedule().Saturday';
if(day == 'Sunday')
  dayOfWeek = '$parent.schedule().Sunday';

return dayOfWeek;
```

}

But the `data-bind` returned is then a string: `checked: $parent.schedule().Monday`, etc.

I would greatly appreciate any help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sounds like you want brackets notation:

```
data-bind="checked: $parent.schedule()[dayOfWeek]"
```

or if `dayOfWeek` is observable (it doesn't look like it in your code, but)

```
data-bind="checked: $parent.schedule()[dayOfWeek()]"
```

As you've pointed out, `.dayOfWeek` looks for a property actually called `dayOfWeek`. `[dayOfWeek]` takes the value of the variable `dayOfWeek` (e.g, `"Friday"` or similar) and then looks up the property with that name.

Comment: Thanks a lot TJ! It works like a charm. Indeed it's not an observable so the first solution is the one I used. I will accept your answer in a few minutes :)